# Facebook post thumbnail size

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, resolution

I have a next problem. In web site i have "like" facebook button. And when I comment page and shared link in small reso I see all good:
[good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QJuS.png)

but in big reso (1680x1050 and more) its not good like:[bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I88Aw.jpg).
I try different size, different proportions and different type. I saw that some post always see good. Can I say Facebook that always show post thumbnail as first variant for all reso???

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Comment: Now my picture only 220x200. This is smaller than 600 x 315 px, but for big resolution show big size post thumbnail.

Comment: So use a bigger image then, and close to the recommended dimensions.

Comment: Follow the [Sharing Best Practices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices)